# Accessing job's configuration from RecordReader / InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Hadoop and I have to create a custom InputFormat.

To do this, I override the InputFormat and RecordReader classes, like it is explained [here](http://bigdatacircus.com/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/)

I would like to access to the configuration of the job (to access to some variable set before running the job). I can access to the "**TaskAttemptContext**" and get a configuration object from this, but this is not the global configuration of the job.

I don't know if what I want is possible but it would be very helpful if you have an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the TaskAttemptContext contains the global configuration, I may made a mistake. So, it is possible to pass variable from the launcher main() to the InputFormat.

Comment: Hi GuillaumeP, how did you get managed with this? I'm in the same situation, dealing with a custom `InputFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem.

In the driver code, set the parameter in your configuration

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setInt ("paramname",value);
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

Access the same in your mapper / reducer using

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
int myParam = conf.getInt("paramname", 0);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to access to the configuration variable from the mapper/reducer but from the InputFormat or RecordReader classes.

Answer (score 0):

The TaskAttempContext will contain the Job level Configuration. The hierarchy is

```
JobContext - contains job level context

TaskAttemptContext - contains TaskAttempt level context + JobContext

TaskInputOutputContext - contains TaskInputOutput level context + TaskAttemptContext +   JobContext

MapContext - contains Mapper specific context + TaskInputOutputContext + TaskAttemptContext +   JobContext

ReduceContext - contains Reducer specific context + TaskInputOutputContext + TaskAttemptContext +   JobContext
```